# Is it better to split one bigger useEffect to multiple when they share the same dependency?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

According to the official React docs, it is recommended to [use multiple useEffects to separate concerns instead of one.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns)
However, I am wondering if that means separating them for example by particular dependency or rather the side effects' logic itself. For example, let's take this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    xyz()
    foo();

    if (instanceOfA(dependency)) {
      bar();
    }

    if (instanceOfB(dependency)) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
       baz();
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [dependency]);
```

Well, they are for sure grouped in this case and depended on the single dependency, but it feels like this useEffect is kind of all over the place.

If I was to refactor it, I would probably split it into smaller useEffects, for example something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    foo()
    xyz()
  }, [dependency])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (instanceOfA(dependency)) {
      bar()
    }
  }, [dependency])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (instanceOfB(dependency)) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        baz()
      }, 1000)

      return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, [dependency])
```

I guess with this approach we have more control over e.g. clean up functions and if needed, all of those hooks could be exported to own custom hooks. On the downside, instead of a single useEffect, we now have 3 different effects to handle.

What would you say is a better pattern in terms of performance / architecture and why?

Comment: Well this is quite a general example, but by separating the `useEffect` hooks you indeed obtain a sometimes much needed "granularity" on these functionalities. I guess it all really depends of what you're really trying to do on each one and if all the processes are independent to one another. Another advantage of this splitting is that if you encounter some problems, it should be easier to debug.